# Why does my IdentityServer4 application fail to start in an Azure WebApp hosting environment?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, identityserver4

I’m attempting to put together a simple identity server following the directions here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/ , and the project runs locally fine, I have only created a new project, not made any modifications.  Running locally it launches, and I can load the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint with no issues.

I take this bare bones project and attempt to upload it to an azure webapp and get the attached:

[image]

HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

It appears that the application fails to start in azure.

I can publish a .NET Core MVC application no problem, but with this IS4 template I always receive the process failure.  What am I missing?  Should this not work out of the box here?

Comment: Whats the underlying error?

Comment: I don't know, logging gives me nothing, the log stream in azure portal just gives me this page in html.

Comment: Only ports 80 and 443 are open for Azure Web App, what is the listen port for your app?

Comment: I haven't specified anything outside the development settings (per the documentation) to listen on 5000.  I assumed (perhaps incorrectly?) that publishing would set that to whatever the hosting environment uses?

Comment: @Aaron Is there a complete sample? I can test it on my side for you.

Comment: `dotnet new is4empty -n IdentityServer`

that's it.  It's a new project, I've changed no code.  I honestly feel like it's a "Oh you just need to do X" in some config that I'm not aware of.  I just don't know what I don't know :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is incorrect and insecure. That default code is there for a reason. During development you have a developer signing credential, for production you have to implement your own signing credential. See the following answer:

[How do I configure "key material" in Identity Server 4 to use SQL, KeyVault, or any other system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771718/how-do-i-configure-key-material-in-identity-server-4-to-use-sql-keyvault-or)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the code in `Startup.cs` file. If you don't run it in development environment, it will throw the exception("need to configure key material"). I just comment these code. Then it works well in Azure.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // uncomment, if you want to add an MVC-based UI
            //services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());

            //if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            //{
                builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    throw new Exception("need to configure key material");
            //}
        }
```

**The result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it was something simple that I just wasn't aware of being new to .net core and identity server.